# Alternative for depreciated widget ancestorWidgetOfExactType

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using an inherited widget in order to build a cart. My cart looks like this:

```dart
    class CartProvider extends InheritedWidget {
      final _cart = Cart();
    
      CartProvider({Key key, Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);
    
      @override
      bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) {
        return false;
      }
    
      static Cart of(BuildContext context) {
        final widget =
            context.ancestorWidgetOfExactType(CartProvider) as CartProvider;
        return widget._cart;
      }
    }
```

I substitute ancestorWidgetOfExactType for findAncestorWidgetOfExactType as recommended by flutter by this:

```dart
  final widget = context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<CartProvider>();
```

I get this error:

> ```
> ../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_google_places-0.2.6/lib/src/flutter_google_places.dart:74:41:
> Error: Method not found: 'TypeMatcher'.
>       context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<PlacesAutocompleteState>());
>                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^                      ../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_google_places-0.2.6/lib/src/flutter_google_places.dart:74:15:
> Error: The method 'ancestorStateOfType' isn't defined for the class
> 'BuildContext'.
>  - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../../Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining
> a method named 'ancestorStateOfType'.
>       context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<PlacesAutocompleteState>());
> 1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:61:47:
> Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
>  - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
> a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
>         GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileOpenDialog).addressOf,                
>                                               ^^^^^^^^^                  ../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:64:46:
> Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'. 
>
>       ^                                                                  ../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:7:
> Error: Struct 'Utf16' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
> class Utf16 extends Struct {                                          
>
>       ^                                                                  ../../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33:
> Error: Expected type 'T' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of
> 'NativeType'.   final int totalSize = count * sizeOf<T>();            
>
>                                 ^                                       
>                                                                         
>                                                                          FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                              
>
>                                                                         
> * Where:                                                                 Script
> '/Users/hsi/Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle'
> line: 991
>                                                                         
> * What went wrong:                                                       Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.            
>
> > Process 'command '/Users/hsi/Desktop/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>                                                                         
> * Try:                                                                   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
> or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
> insights.
>                                                                         
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> ```

I have tried on every channel but cannot get a solution. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I formatted your code a bit to make to styled better and now its working. Also created a mock Cart class but you can use yours instead. If it helps, the differences are,

1. CartProvider has a child field, so that it can easily inserted into the widget tree (this is similar to provider package). This uses 'dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType' method instead of 'ancestorWidgetOfExactType' which is deprecated.
2. Build method returns a CartProvider where I instantiate the Card() and added MaterialApp as the child of this, which make sure every child of MaterialApp will have access to cart.
3. Lastly, inside the MyHomePage widget, I am fetching the injected object using "CartProvider.of" method and using it in the body of the widget.

Hope that is clear.

a. CartProvider

=====================================

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'cart.dart';

class CartProvider extends InheritedWidget {

  CartProvider({@required this.cart, @required this.child});

  final Cart cart;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(covariant InheritedWidget oldWidget) => false;

  static Cart of(BuildContext context) {
    CartProvider provider =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<CartProvider>();
    return provider.cart;
  }
}
```

=============

b. main file

==============

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'cart_provider.dart';
import 'cart.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Injecting cart using the created CartProvider
    return CartProvider(
      cart: Cart(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    //Accessing the cart inside a child widget
    final cart = CartProvider.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hello'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            //Using cart widget
            Text(cart.myCart),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

===========

c. Mock Cart class

======================

```
class Cart {
  final myCart = 'My cart';
}
```